# Access JSON Elements with Javascript Function to load content dynamically

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to load my content dynamically with JSON and JavaScript. Unfortunately, when trying to iterate all the elements in my JSON, I get the following error function

```
loadContent.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at loadContent.js:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

My function to access the json looks my JavaScript looks like this:

```
function loadJSON(path) {
    fetch("../data/main.json")
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)

            data.forEach(element => {
                //Befüllung von <template für artikel>

                var first = document.getElementById('first');
                var clone = first.content.cloneNode(true);

                clone.querySelector('figure a') = element.url;
                clone.querySelector('.article-content a h2') = element.heading;
                clone.querySelector('img') = element.src;


                document.getElementsByClassName('hero-inner').appendChild(clone);
            });
        })
        .then((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

The JSON looks the following:

```
[{
    "url": "https://futurezone.at/science/alles-zu-meteoriten-und-asteroiden-die-sich-2020-der-erde-naehern/401027129",
    "src": "img/rightsection/pc/asteroiden.jpg",
    "data": "Tauriden-Meteorschauer erreicht Höhepunkt"
}]
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You are assigning directly to node. Try assigning to properties of node like for data , clone.querySelector('.selector').innerText = element.data;

Comment: When I try to assign it directly with help of ``innerText`` I get the error ``Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null``

Comment: check the selector again, maybe it's typo

Comment: yeah thanks, the selector was wrong